# 200+ instances for fglrx?

Tags: kernel-modules, fglrx

I was browsing the basic info about the modules that my kernel is currently using on a machine I have, and this piece of information pops up.

```
$ grep fglrx /proc/modules 
fglrx 8085343 200 - Live 0x0000000000000000 (POF)
```

and there are also times where that `200` becomes something near to `300` or `250` .

Really there are 200+ instances of the driver for my GPU ? I'm doing something wrong here ? What's the optimal number ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that that count details other modules that are depending that specific module:

```
lsmod | grep radeon
Module                  Size  Used by
radeon               1285868  3 
i2c_algo_bit           12751  1 radeon
drm_kms_helper         39892  1 radeon
ttm                    69624  1 radeon
```

and that those are not instances *per-se* of the module on your system, but references to parts of the modules. If you use Games, 3D/2D effects, and other nifty things that gets managed by the GPU, that number will rise since more graphics subroutines will be used. The number represents the use count, how many things are currently depending on that module. This number you cannot tweak it or control it (unless you control what you execute) and is pretty harmless whatever the value it has.

References:

- http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Module-HOWTO/#PROCMODULES

Comment: that is the count of the opengl contexts opened on my GPU by any chance ?

Comment: @user2485710 that and more. Any reference/dependency on the module will show up there.